# Load página dentro de uma div com Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, apache

Boa tarde!

Estou tentando usar o Ajax pra carregar uma página dentro de uma div que tenho, mas está dando erro 403 (Forbidden). No caso eu não posso fazer isso? Teria como eu fazer de outro jeito?

OBS: A página que quero dar o load é do zendesk.

```
$j.ajax({
        url: "https://livreeleve.zendesk.com/hc/pt-br",
        type: "POST",
        beforeSend: function(){
            $j('.main-container.col1-layout').html('Carregando...');
        },
        success: function(r){
            $j('.main-container.col1-layout').html(r);
        }
});
```

---

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://www.livreeleve.com.br' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Meu domínio é www.livreeleve.com.br

No caso, eu só consigo fazer isso liberando acesso pelo htaccess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim esse problema se dá por causa das configurações de CORS, que é uma proteção contra requisições de outros domínios ao seu site, proibindo-as de exibi-lo em um `iframe` por exemplo, como forma de prevenção à clickjacking e outros tipos de exploit.

Para conseguir acessar o seu website por meio de uma requisição de outro site, você precisará alterar seu arquivo `htaccess`, adicionando a seguinte linha (levando em consideração o seu site):

`Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://www.livreeleve.com.br"`

Dá uma olhada aqui se precisar de mais info.: [CORS no Apache](https://imasters.com.br/front-end/html/defina-cabecalhos-access-control-allow-origin-cors-no-apache-vhost-ou-htaccess/?trace=1519021197&source=single)